# Why are the total (non-distinct) Hamiltonian circuits in complete graph $K_n$ $=$ $(n−1)!$

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2131426/855953) on a very similar question which says:

> Total (non-distinct) Hamiltonian circuits in complete graph $K_n$ is $(n−1)!$
>
> This follows from the fact that starting from any vertex we have $n−1$ edges to choose from first vertex, $n−2$ edges to choose from second vertex, $n−3$ to choose from the third and so on. These being independent choices, we get $(n−1)!$ possible number of choices.

I have seen many textbooks which mention the exact same reasoning, but what I do not understand is the fixed choice of the starting vertex.

Since the starting vertex itself can be chosen in $n$ ways, we should have $n!$ total Hamiltonian circuits and not $(n-1)!$.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: Consider the complete graph on vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Are $1 \sim 2 \sim 3 \sim 1$ and $2 \sim 3 \sim 1 \sim 2$ the same circuit, or different?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That is the same circuit, but I'm still a bit confused as to why this works. Say our starting vertex is $1$ and we either select the edge to $2$ or $3$. Without the loss of generality, let's say we select $1 \sim 2$. Now we have a circuit which is $1 \sim 2 \sim 3 \sim 1$. Now, what would happen if we didn't have starting vertex as $1$? We could've had a circuit $2 \sim 1 \sim 3 \sim 2$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. My above case is incorrect. $2 \sim 1 \sim 3 \sim 2$ is equivalent to $1 \sim 3 \sim 2 \sim 1$ which would've been there had we considered the first edge to be $1 \sim 3$.

Comment: You got it.  Your method of choosing an initial vertex first will count each circuit $n$ times instead of once.  So the total number of distinct circuits is $n!/n = (n-1)!$.

Comment: You can answer your own question now, and accept your answer, so that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue. (or you can delete the question)

Comment: @EthanBolker done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to merge my discussion with [Matthew Leingang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2785/matthew-leingang) in the comments into an answer.

Consider the complete graph on vertices $\{1,2,3\}$.
Here $1 \sim 2 \sim 3 \sim 1$ and $2 \sim 3 \sim 1 \sim 2$ are equivalent circuits.

#### Now, why does it work?

---

Say our starting vertex is $1$ and we either select the edge to $2$ or $3$. Without the loss of generality, let's say we select $1 \sim 2$. Now we have a circuit which is $1 \sim 2 \sim 3 \sim 1$.

Now, what would happen if we didn't have starting vertex as $1$? We could've had a circuit $2 \sim 1 \sim 3 \sim 2$. However, this is equivalent to $1 \sim 3 \sim 2 \sim 1$ which would've been there had we considered the first edge to be $1 \sim 3$.

#### Conclusion

---

The method of choosing an initial vertex first will count each circuit $n$ times instead of once. So, the total number of distinct circuits is:

 
$n!$ $/$ $n$ $=$ $(n−1)!$

Comment: You merged the answer into the question - but the question still has no posted answer, so folks will find it when looking for open questions.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't understand. I have answered the question and not merged it into the question.

Comment: Sorry - didn't check where I was on the page. +1 for the answer.